# How to change proxy settings using python in windows 8?

Tags: python, windows-8, internet-explorer-10

how can i set proxy settings using python in windows8? I tried this code but not working.. Settings not changing

```
def inst_proxy5(self):
    """ sets institute proxy"""
    INTERNET_SETTINGS = winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER,
    r'Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings',
    0, winreg.KEY_ALL_ACCESS)
    def set_key(name, value):
        _, reg_type = winreg.QueryValueEx(INTERNET_SETTINGS, name)
        winreg.SetValueEx(INTERNET_SETTINGS, name, 0, reg_type, value)
    set_key('ProxyEnable', 1)
    set_key('ProxyOverride', u'*.local;<local>')  # Bypass the proxy for localhost
    set_key('ProxyServer', u'192.168.0.5:3128')
    root.destroy()`
```

If i comment this its working.. how to set this also

```
set_key('ProxyOverride', u'*.local;<local>')  # Bypass the proxy for localhost
```

Its giving this error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python26\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1410, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\py_pro\but1.py", line 82, in inst_proxy22
    set_key('ProxyOverride', u'*.local;<local>')  # Bypass the proxy for localhost
  File "C:\py_pro\but1.py", line 79, in set_key
    _, reg_type = winreg.QueryValueEx(INTERNET_SETTINGS, name)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Do you get an error when running the code? Does the code run successfully, but the registry is not changed?

Comment: settings not changing. even after restart

Comment: you could try to pass `reg_type` explicitly without reading the possibly non-existing key first.